# How to Completely reset SSH for git

Tags: git, github, ssh

When I want to commit sth, in GitHub Desktop or Visual Studio or VS Code, I get this error:

`error: Couldn't load public key \\: No such file or directory?`

I had tried to use ssh for my github, but now even I can't make a local commit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: IF you're getting this message with doing `git commit`, which should not try to use ssh, there might be a problem with your Git configuration. Run `git config --list --show-origin` and scan for something to do with a public key, or maybe ssh, and hopefully the problem will jump out at you. If you find something there, you can edit the file shown and delete the problematic line.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I entered ``git config --global commit.gpgsign false`` & that disabled gpg sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Upgrading my comment to an answer, since it solved the problem.]

If you're getting this message when doing `git commit`, which should not try to use ssh, there might be a problem with your Git configuration. Run

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

and scan for something to do with a public key, or maybe ssh, and hopefully the problem will jump out at you.

If you find something there, you can edit the file shown and delete the problematic line.

Comment: The OP mentioned `commit.gpgSign`. If this is set to `true`, then `git commit` is equivalent to `git commit -S`, i.e., sign each commit. If `gpg.format` is set to `ssh` as well (and your Git version is new enough: ssh signing was new in Git 2.34), `git commit` will invoke ssh to compute the commit signature.

Comment: In any case, the actual problem is not in Git itself, but in some ssh configuration file. Of course, disabling signed GPG commits will sidestep the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Configure again your access. In my opinion is safest way.
Delete all in your ~/.ssh directory and make a new ssh-key.

Once clean up, go again:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C “your_email@gmail.com”
```

Continue with enter, enter and enter just add a secure pass

Now, see your new files:

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

And check that the ssh server is on

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

If everything its ok, add your private key

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now read and copy your public key to add its on your GitHub page config

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```